# How can I cross compile a 32-bit Linux kernel for ARM64 with armv8l-gnueabi?

Tags: linux, 32-bit, arm64, armv8

I am working on compiling a 32-bit Linux kernel (4.4.x) to run on an ARM64 device. I am using *armv8l-linux-gnueabihf* gcc from Linaro.

To compile the Linux kernel, I run the following commands:

```
# run defconfig with COMPAT enabled to enable EL0 to run 32bit
> make defconfig
> make
```

I get the following error:

> ./arch/arm64/include/uapi/asm/ptrace.h:76:2: error: unknown type name '__uint128_t'

It seems that the 32-bit GCC compiler does not know how to use 128-bit variables.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: this might be better on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: From what I now understand of the CONFIG_COMPAT option, I would say that 1) you don't need it if you compile a 32-bit kernel because you will only be able to run 32 bits executables anyway 2) if you want to use it, you will need to build a 64-bit kernel. The fact that you are using an option that does only make sense in a 64-bit kernel when compiling a 32-bit kernel would explain why there is an error related to __uint128_t.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
I agree, that there is no reason for the 32bit kernel. After many inquiries it also appears that ARM has made many changes that block this option in latest kernels. I know older kernel might support it, for example for RPI3 that has 32bit kernel.

Comment: Older kernels compiled in 64-bit mode you mean.

Comment: I meant that for RPI3 it has a 32bit kernel, while the device is ARMv8